# Duplicate digital signature fields generated from WordprocessingDocument.Open method

Tags: c#

If I place signature field inside shape diagram and create a document template, then WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream,true) method generate document xml which has duplicate o:signatureline tags.
If I place signature field separately, then it is generated node uniquely

I don't know why it behaves differently in above scenario.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language and library are you using? What kind of code snippets can you share?

Comment: thanks Margus, C# app uses DocumentFormat.OpenXml component to retrieve signatures in a dotx file